# Visual Studio: Can't disable exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2013

I can't seem to disable a lot of exceptions in Visual Studio 2013. I want to disable Managed>LoaderLock when it is user-unhanded, but I can't.

[image: Debug>Exceptions menu screenshot in Visual Studio 2013]

Does anyone know how to fix this? My  project is a C++ DLL, but the application it is loaded into throws this exception a lot, so I want to disable it.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"?   The exception is thrown, and has to go somewhere.  This dialog is used to configure the debugger to break execution when the exception is not handled in code, and, since it is checked, when the exception is thrown.  You can uncheck the "thrown" box and the debugger won't stop unless the exception is unhandled and your program will terminate with the unhandled exception.  Since your app throws LoaderLock a lot it should be handling it.

Comment: It's not my app that the DLL is being loaded into so that's not an option :( I understand what you're saying - at the moment Visual Studio breaks on this exception 4 times each time I start debugging. I hit 'continue' each time, and can then debug normally, but it's really annoying. I was hoping visual studio could automatically 'continue' so I don't have to manually click it each time.

Comment: Uncheck the 'thrown' box, then the debugger won't stop unless the exception is unhandled (and it sounds like your 3rd part app is handling it).

Comment: When I uncheck 'Thrown' VS still breaks each time.